# Rails 3.0.0 and FASTCGI Deployment Question

Tags: deployment, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have hostingrails.com. But following their tutorial on deploying rails application with FASTCGI is not quite working... So currently I'm hosting one of my apps with them using Thin.

Currently, my host says FASTCGI and Rails3 is not supported is this true?

Besides running mongrel,thin or passenger. What other options do I have with my host? They are telling me to develop in 2.3.8 if I want to use fastcgi, but I'm trying to move away from 2.3.8 and to rails 3.0.0.

Anyone have a better shared host? Basically what I am looking for is a shared host allowing me to host multiple rails 3.0.0 applications. I'm not expecting alot of usage but I'm looking to build like a portfolio of applications that I've made and would like them hosted on.

And with hosting rails i'm spending $7/month. I'm looking for something in this ball park or maybe a few more dollars. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend dreamhost. it is hands down the best shared host I have tried over the years, and they do support rails.

Not rails 3 though. I got it working using this http://blog.joeygeiger.com/2010/05/17/i-beat-dreamhost-how-to-really-get-rails-3-bundler-and-dreamhost-working/

Finally, there are things that you just can't do on a shared host. Keep in mind you can get a pretty decent vps (like linode 512) for 20$/mo